# How is javascript compiled by v8?

Tags: v8, libv8

Take the [hello-world](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/samples/hello-world.cc) as an example. 
I have couple of questions:

1. What does `v8::Isolate` do? Does it create an new thread
2. What does `v8::Isolate::Scope` do?
3. What does `v8::HandleScope` do?
4. What does `v8::Local<v8::Context>` do?
5. What does `v8::Script::Compile`  do? Does it compile the js code directly to machine code?

Thanks your for your help!

Comment: This is probably too many questions for a question.

Comment: JavaScript cannot be _trivially_ compiled to machine-code the way that C (for example) can because JavaScript lacks type information. Consequently JavaScript JIT compilers are incredibly advanced and are a current research hot-topic. So I don't think it's possible to give a short answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [official wiki](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Embedding#hello-world):

> - An isolate is a VM instance with its own heap.
> - A local handle is a pointer to an object. All V8 objects are accessed using handles, they are necessary because of the way the V8 garbage collector works.
> - A handle scope can be thought of as a container for any number of handles. When you've finished with your handles, instead of deleting each one individually you can simply delete their scope.
> - A context is an execution environment that allows separate, unrelated, JavaScript code to run in a single instance of V8. You must explicitly specify the context in which you want any JavaScript code to be run.
>
> These concepts are discussed in greater detail in the [Embedder's Guide](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Embedder%27s-Guide).

Once you've read the existing documentation, if anything is still unclear, please ask more specific questions.

Regarding (5): In current versions of V8, `v8::Script::Compile` compiles bytecode for V8's interpreter. In earlier versions, it compiled unoptimized machine code. The difference is an internal implementation detail that you don't need to worry about :-)